# How to register a non-canonical hardware controller as an inputDevice in Android?

Tags: java, android, controller, wifi, android-hardware

my problem is a little tricky. I should connect an external controller to Android system and make it available for third party apps. Unfortunatly, the controller just sends 3 kind of signal: accelerometer, pressure and of course battery level. Before, suggest me to search for joystics of something else. I try but due to the singularity of this controller, I'm not quite sure that it's gonna work that way. Infact, the controller talk to the phone via a WIFI ad-hoc network and it doesn't send any sort of managing signal to try to connect as a game controller, for example.

I searched inside the source and I saw a class that maybe would come in a handy: InputDevice class. As far as i can see, it has a lot of predefined profile but I can't find a way to "register" my controller as a new InputDevice.

hope the problem it's enough clear

I'm sorry not to be more specific but it's a business project and I've signed an NDA